# Installation of mac brew vim version 8.1

Tags: homebrew, vi

I'm using brew vim which is currently at version 8.0.1850 but 8.1 has just been released and I'm wondering if there is a way to upgrade to it yet? I've done some digging and can't see an option to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pull request on homebrew's github to update the Vim formula to 8.1: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/27983

When that merges, just run `brew upgrade vim`.

If you want to install 8.1 yourself, you can do so by cloning and following the build instructions on the vim official repo: https://github.com/vim/vim.

Answer (score 0):

vim 8.1 is out now in homebrew

```
$ brew info vim
vim: stable 8.1.0200 (bottled), HEAD
Vi 'workalike' with many additional features
https://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with:
  ex-vi (because vim and ex-vi both install bin/ex and bin/view)
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/vim.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: perl ✘, ruby ✘
Recommended: python ✔
Optional: gettext ✔, lua ✔, luajit ✘, python@2 ✔
==> Options
```